# Why use a '@' paramDefaults values in $resource (Angular 1.3.5)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

```
// Angular factory
wpApp.factory('Posts', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(appInfo.api_url + 'posts/:ID', {
    ID: "@id"
  })
});

// Index page controller.
wpApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Posts', function ($scope, Posts) {
  $scope.page_title = "Blog Listing";
  Posts.query(function(res) {
    $scope.posts = res;
  })
}]);

// Show page controller.
wpApp.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Posts', function($scope, $stateParams, Posts) {
  console.log($stateParams);
  Posts.get({ ID : $stateParams.id }, function(res) {
    $scope.post = res;
  });
}]);

// Angular app configuration.
wpApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state( 'list', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'ListCtrl',
      templateUrl: appInfo.template_directory + 'templates/list.html'
    })
    .state('detail', {
      url: '/posts/:id',
      controller: 'DetailCtrl',
      templateUrl: appInfo.template_directory + 'templates/detail.html'
    })
});
```

From code in **DetailsCtrl**, I understood that we are going to do a **GET** request by calling url with id == id passed to angular url params.

But what does this `ID: "@id"` do? What is it used for? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @, then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object (provided when calling actions with a request body). For example, if the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of someParam will be data.someProp. Note that the parameter will be ignored, when calling a "GET" action method (i.e. an action method that does not accept a request body)

So in your case that second argument is simply configuring defaults for your URI. In this case it is making the URI value of `ID` dynamic.

Comment: I understood the :ID part in the URI. But I still don't understand how ID: @id will come into play, can you explain using some code?